# Unable to Load one yml.erb file in another yml.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, erb

I have 2 files (yml.erb) and I am trying to include one file in another. The problem I am facing is that resulting file is not formatted properly as required.

File 1: Main File ( test.yml.erb , in which I am trying to include another file)

```
type:     map
mapping:
  aaaaaaa:
    type: str
  bbbbbbbbbbb:
    type: seq
    sequence:
      - type: map
        mapping:
          cccccccccc:
            type: seq
            sequence:
              - type: map
                mapping:
                <%= ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/#{"hc.yml.erb"}")).result %>
```

File 2  : (This file I am trying to include in File 1)

```
health_check:
type: map
name: HEALTH_CHECK
mapping:
  path: { type: str, required: false }
  grace_period: { type: int, range: { min: 30, max: 450}, required: false }
```

When I am trying to parse Main.yml.erb file using

> ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/#{"test.yml.erb"}")).result)

Result : (See formatting of health_check)

```
type:     map
mapping:
  aaaaaaa:
    type: str
  bbbbbbbbbbb:
    type: seq
    sequence:
      - type: map
        mapping:
          cccccccccc:
            type: seq
            sequence:
              - type: map
                mapping:
                health_check:
type: map
name: HEALTH_CHECK
mapping:
  path: { type: str, required: false }
  grace_period: { type: int, range: { min: 30, max: 450}, required: false }
```

Expectation :

```
type:     map
mapping:
  aaaaaaa:
    type: str
  bbbbbbbbbbb:
    type: seq
    sequence:
      - type: map
        mapping:
          cccccccccc:
            type: seq
            sequence:
              - type: map
                mapping:
                  health_check:
                    type: map
                    name: HEALTH_CHECK
                    mapping:
                      path: { type: str, required: false }
                      grace_period: { type: int, range: { min: 30, max: 450}, required: false }
```

NOTE : I need to parse the resulting YAML file , so it has to be properly formatted.

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirements, but another option is to parse both files, add things together in ruby, and then export the result to YAML. It seems like you're trying to do a lot in YAML, and it might be easier to handle the problem in ruby.

Comment: Another thought, try replacing newlines with new line and additional spacing: File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/#{"hc.yml.erb"}").gsub("\n", "\n\t\t\t\t")

Comment: We are using Kwalify library to validate YAML . Since that YAML file is getting big , I though to bifurcate it and hence the above requirement. Main issue I am facing is that <%= ERB.new(.... %> line is not getting replaces at exact same place due to which resulting YAML file becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to indent things so that the resulting YAML file is properly formatted but I wish there would be a better way to do the same. Here is my solution which is working fine

`<%= ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/#{"hc.yml.erb"}")).result.gsub!(/\n/, "\n#{"\s" * 20}") %>`

Essentially I formatted the "including" yaml file so that is aligns fine with the main yaml.